# Understanding a C++ Shell sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Hi I am trying to learn the shell sort .I understand the basic principles of splitting into segments and using the insertion method to sort.

However I only understand this example of code I found up to a point. If anyone could give me a clear explanation of what each of the for loops do etc. would be great.

```
int const size = 5;
int i, j, increment, temp;
int array[size]={4,5,2,3,6},i1=0;
//split the array into segments unil we reach beginning of array    
for(increment = size/2;increment > 0; increment /= 2)
{
    for(i = increment; i<size; i++)
    {
        temp = array[i];
        for(j = i; j >= increment ;j-=increment)
        {
            //perform the insertion sort for this section
            if(temp < array[j-increment])
            {
                array[j] = array[j-increment];
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug it to get an understanding what each code line does to the variables involved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(increment = size/2;increment > 0; increment /= 2)
```

This for loop initializes the gap between the elements in the array you are comparing against. So increment is set to 2 initially.

```
for(i = increment; i<size; i++)
{
    temp = array[i];
```

This says, start at element 3 and go forwards until you reach element 5, we will see why soon.

```
for(j = i; j >= increment ;j-=increment)
{
    //perform the insertion sort for this section
    if(temp < array[j-increment])
    {
        array[j] = array[j-increment];
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
array[j] = temp;
```

Says ok, we are starting at the element specified above (in this case, the 2nd index), and we are going to compare it against the element that is the "gap" length behind it. So it would take the 3rd element, and compare it against the 1st element. If the **3rd** element is **smaller** than the **1st** element, swap them, otherwise break out of the loop. We then decrement our index by the size of the gap (from 2 to 0) and keep going if our new index is at least as large as the size of the gap (so we don't have array out of bounds issues).

Now we go back to the middle for loop and increment the element position we start at; so  we compare the

- 4th element against the 2nd element. Stop
- 5th element against the 3rd, then 3rd against the 1st. Stop

Once we have compared all elements within their "gap" length, we go back and change the gap length to half of what it was before, rinse and repeat, until it reaches 0.

Typically, you don't want to just divide the gap in half - there are pre-defined functions for gap length recommendation (usually primes). [See wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) for more info.